# Flutter App crashes when loading map from google_maps_place_picker

Tags: flutter, google-maps, flutter-dependencies

I implemented the plugin google_maps_place_picker on my Flutter project, but when I enter the page to display the map it starts to charge but suddenly crashed but show no error and I can't do anything, go the last page or something.

My friend downloaded and runned the code but in his computer and phone, that is a bit older than mine, just works perfectly.

Does anybody know what could it be or what could I do?

Comment: Can you provide the related code scope and crash log ?